# Can you use someone as a human shield?

Tags: combat, rogue-trader, grapple

With human shield I mean grabbing someone [like this](http://www.imfdb.org/images/thumb/a/a6/SCC-USP_Human_Shield.jpg/600px-SCC-USP_Human_Shield.jpg) and using him as a mobile cover while you can still shoot your enemies. I thought this would be covered in the Grapple rules, but to my surprise there is no mention to this tactic. I'd like to know if there's any rule for this sort of action in this book, or any of the 40k RPG books made by FFG.

If there are no rules explaining this, how could I make house rules to make this work? The character grabbing the other one should be able to shoot one handed weapons, and anyone who tried to shoot him should aim for the head or hit the grabbed guy.

Answer (score 4):

House rule (although more of a GM circumstantial on-the-spot call, really):

When in control of a grapple, you can use your opponent as a human shield, providing AP 4 (or their armor's AP rating, if higher) cover to the body.

This feels like it dovetails with the existing rules, using the existing grapple and cover mechanics.  The human (or whatever race they may be!) shield thus is used as AP 4 cover to the body, meaning any damage to that location first goes through the cover, while allowing someone to aim for a limb or head shot (this part mostly because that's the standard cinematic takedown for someone using a human shield - aim carefully for an exposed arm, leg, or head).